# can the layout of text in android views be controlled?

Tags: android, text, formatting

I am looking to format text line by line in a text view or similar. I want to be able to have line by line justifcation and formatting, almost like a word document (though nothing like as extensive)

I basically need to be able to have a continuous document with some parts right justified, some parts centered. Some bold, some not and some with a coloured background and some white. Also alowing the user to choose font.

Can someone recommend an decent approach to this please.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

TextView/EditText operates on fairly rich text described by the various style span objects here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html

For example you can use this to build text containing those various style spans: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html

SpannableStringBuilder is-a CharSequence, so it can be set as the text in a TextView.  Though more often you probably just want to use TextView.getEditableText() to return the Editable interface to the text inside of the text view which allows you to modify its contents including style spans.

TextView supports most of what you are asking for through style spans, though justification is applied per-paragraph and not per-line.  (Per-line is weird...  I don't think even Word does such a thing?)

Comment: I think I should clarify perhaps. Based on what you have said its more by section or I guess as you say by paragraph that I mean. In which case what you say will likely do the job. It would probably be easier if I could tell you exactly what it is I am trying to achieve but for the moment I prefer not to give that away. Lets say I want a single line with a background in bold, right justified. I want a single line centered in bold but also that is restricted to a given length. I then want a paragraph centered, of line length so it wraps and does not go all the way across the page.

Comment: The possible bounds depends on the style.  Character styles like bold, color, etc can be applied to any character range.  Paragraph styles like justification need to be applied to ranges that are paragraphs.  There is no basic concept of a "line" for applying styles because lines are purely a side-effect of layout within the bounds of the text view, not a structural part of the text.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using multiple TextViews. Possibly, one for each line if you really need the text that different. You can customize each one however you want fairly easily. If you haven't already, take a look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html
Then, you could use a RelativeLayout or a LinearLayout to position them however you need. Just ask if you have any other questions.